# Vertical center custom font in React native iOS

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-ios

Using React Native with Expo.
Having difficulties centering custom imported font, at iOS.
Android rendering with no issues, the text is vertically centered perfectly. Using iOS it is slightly upper than the center.

(Native Font centering well on both emulators - Android and iOS).

Any ideas how this could be solved?

Code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Font } from 'expo';

export default class  extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isReady: false
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'KlavikaBold': require('./KlavikaBold.otf'),
    });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <Expo.AppLoading />;
      }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.content}>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    color: 'white',
    padding: 10,
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'KlavikaBold',
    fontSize: 20,
  }

})
```

[image][image]

Comment: could you please attach an image, how it looks like and how you would like to have it ?

Comment: @TimH Updated with images.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an easy solution that worked for me...

> 1. Download Font Tools for Xcode
> 2. In Terminal run $ ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A d pathtoyourfont.ttf
> 3. Edit dumped pathtoyourfont.hhea.xml and set lineGap="0"
> 4. If lineGap was 200 and ascender="800", set ascender to the sum ot these two 1000
> 5. In Terminal run $ ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A f pathtoyourfont.ttf
>
> Done. Your new values are fused back the font file.
>
> Repeat steps 4 and 5 until the rendering is OK. Do not change other values. Those should be OK.
>
> Value that finally worked for me was ascender="1050". Try to change the sum until Android and iOS render the  component the same height.

Source: https://medium.com/@martin_adamko/consistent-font-line-height-rendering-42068cc2957d

Comment: I downloaded Font Tools for XCode but I'm unable to use it due to `command not found: ftxdumperfuser`. Did you have the same issue?

Comment: @Gus you may need to add the installed commands to your PATH for your shell configuration.

> The command-line utilities are installed in /Library/Apple/usr/bin/. [...] Make sure you have removed such copies (if necessary), or that in your $PATH environment variable starts with /Library/Apple/usr/bin/.

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/

Answer (score 6):

On iOS `textAlignVertical: 'center'` has no effect, but you can achieve a similar result when setting the `lineHeight` to the doubled height of the `fontSize`.

We only need to apply the doubled lineHeight on iOS, therefore we import `Platform`

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform } from 'react-native';   // add Platform at the beginning
```

and then change the following:

```
<Text style={[styles.content, {lineHeight: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 20 }]}>Home!</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `lineHeight` did not centered perfectly. However I liked your idea with `Platform`.

Comment: @Rukala You’re welcome. The above lineHeight rule works well with the standard font. Because your are using an imported font, you probably have to adapt the values to perfectly center your Text. Hope it will help you.

Comment: This is not the best way to handle it. If you change the device the alignments will change

Answer (score 1):

you can make vertical center using following 2 style

```
...Platform.select({ios: {lineHeight: verticalScale(55)}, android: {textAlignVertical: 'center',}}),
    height: verticalScale(55),
```

here height and lineHeight must be same.

Answer (score 0):

Same concept as detailed above but I found that using [Glyphs](https://glyphsapp.com/) was easy as well.  Simply open the custom font you are working with and then once opened in Glyphs hit the "info" icon to bring you to a screen that allows you to adjust the ascender, descender, and lineGap properties.  Export the new settings and keep adjusting until you get it to look as needed.

Answer (score -1):

{{alignSelf: "center"}}