# Font is not vertically centred in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, fonts

When I unset the font-family property the text is centred, so it must be an issue with the font I'm using which is Google's [Poppins](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins?query=poppins).

I've found similar issues around using custom fonts

- [Vertical center custom font in React native iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767007/vertical-center-custom-font-in-react-native-ios/54591266#54591266)
- [Offset in custom font's vertical alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023318/offset-in-custom-fonts-vertical-alignment/57023319#57023319)

though interestingly the trouble with those are with iOS and not Android. I thought I cracked it with these steps:

1. Install [Font Tools for Xcode 14](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Font%20Tools%20for%20Xcode)
2. Run `ftxdumperfuser -t OS/2 -A d Poppins-Medium.ttf` to produce `Poppins-Medium.OS_2.xml`
3. Modify `typoAscender` and `typoDescender` properties inside the xml
4. Apply the xml changes to the font with `ftxdumperfuser -t OS/2 -A f Poppins-Medium.ttf`

Though I later found that this only resolves the vertical alignment issue with Android phones using Android API level 33. Android phones using API level 32 <= are completely unaffected by this change, and I cannot find a fix for this or any change regarding fonts in the android api release notes. I also have doubts that the solution I have tried is the correct one, given that the font I'm using is one of Google's.

Android API level 33 with my patched Poppins font (centred):
[image: Android API level 33 with my patched Poppins font (centred)]

Android API level 32 with my patched Poppins font (not centred):
[image: Android API level 32 with my patched Poppins font (not centred)]

Android API level 32 with system font (centred):
[image: Android API level 32 with system font (centred)]

I am running a `yarn create expo-app` project, with Poppins fonts install under `/assets/fonts/` and the following App.js file:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { useFonts } from "expo-font";

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "Poppins-Medium": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 500 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium" }}>Hello</Text>
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

What am I missing here to have Poppins fonts vertically aligned for Android API level 32<= ?

Comment: Hey @SimonReggiani sorry to have left you there. I never figured this out, have you encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched this through the Internet and found a possible answer. It's working for me perfectly

Just add `<item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>` in the style.xml (/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml) file and rebuild the app.

For more information https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/3457

Comment: Ty that makes a big improvement! Though there is still some misalignment remaining. Looking at the `includeFontPadding` description: "For best results also set textAlignVertical to center", I found making that second change completed the vertical alignment.

It's a pity that <item name="android: textAlignVertical">center</item> isn't a valid option. As I need both `includeFontPadding: false` and `textAlignVertical: 'center'` for the vertical alignment to work, I've replaced every `Text` component imported from `react-native` with a custom `Text` component with just those 2 options set.